# Ubuntu 18.04: Ethernet keeps dropping randomly for several seconds

Tags: networking, 18.04, ethernet

Recently I have installed a new router because of a internet provider change and since then my previously faithful ethernet connection makes problems. Even though internet access and the network in general works, the ethernet connection fails every now and then for several seconds. It seems to happen preferably when starting large/fast downloads but will also happen while doing things not obviously network related.

Here are my hardware specs:

```
julian@julian-desktop:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -i net -A2
24:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak] [8086:24fb] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2110]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
--
25:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1539] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [1849:1539]
    Kernel driver in use: igb
    Kernel modules: igb
```

And ifconfig:

```
julian@julian-desktop:~$ ifconfig
enp37s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.178.42  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.178.255
        inet6 fe80::4a89:a9d2:49ca:9df4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 70:85:c2:a8:bb:7f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 333573  bytes 479511002 (479.5 MB)
        RX errors 2  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 1
        TX packets 180965  bytes 14125591 (14.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xf7500000-f751ffff  

enp3s0f0u3c4i2: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 42:33:1a:65:b8:0c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Lokale Schleife)
        RX packets 6415  bytes 586547 (586.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6415  bytes 586547 (586.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp36s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.42.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.42.0.255
        inet6 fe80::d7d4:24b5:9682:47bb  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 3c:6a:a7:4e:40:f8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 104  bytes 11975 (11.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 303  bytes 47366 (47.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

And here is the log from /var/log/syslog one of the disconnection periods:

```
Apr 15 17:52:46 julian-desktop kernel: [ 1657.601916] igb 0000:25:00.0 enp37s0: igb: enp37s0 NIC Link is Down
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop wpa_supplicant[1338]: message repeated 21 times: [ wlp36s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-95 retry=1]
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop NetworkManager[1320]: <info>  [1555343572.1914] device (enp37s0): state change: activated -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop NetworkManager[1320]: <info>  [1555343572.2074] dhcp4 (enp37s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 4430
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop NetworkManager[1320]: <info>  [1555343572.2074] dhcp4 (enp37s0): state changed bound -> done
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop avahi-daemon[1334]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.178.42 on enp37s0.
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop avahi-daemon[1334]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp37s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.178.42.
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop avahi-daemon[1334]: Interface enp37s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop avahi-daemon[1334]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::4a89:a9d2:49ca:9df4 on enp37s0.
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop avahi-daemon[1334]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp37s0.IPv6 with address fe80::4a89:a9d2:49ca:9df4.
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop avahi-daemon[1334]: Interface enp37s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop NetworkManager[1320]: <info>  [1555343572.2104] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop NetworkManager[1320]: <info>  [1555343572.2111] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop dbus-daemon[1302]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.13' (uid=0 pid=1320 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop whoopsie[2042]: [17:52:52] offline
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop dnsmasq[1846]: lese /etc/resolv.conf
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop dnsmasq[1846]: Benutze Namensserver 127.0.0.53#53
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop dnsmasq[1846]: Cache geleert
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop dnsmasq[1846]: lese /etc/resolv.conf
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop dnsmasq[1846]: Benutze Namensserver 127.0.0.53#53
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop dnsmasq[1846]: Cache geleert
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop dnsmasq[1846]: lese /etc/resolv.conf
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop dnsmasq[1846]: Benutze Namensserver 127.0.0.53#53
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop dnsmasq[1846]: Cache geleert
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop dnsmasq[1846]: lese /etc/resolv.conf
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop dnsmasq[1846]: Benutze Namensserver 127.0.0.53#53
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop dnsmasq[1846]: Cache geleert
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop dnsmasq[1846]: lese /etc/resolv.conf
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop dnsmasq[1846]: Benutze Namensserver 127.0.0.53#53
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop dnsmasq[1846]: Cache geleert
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop dnsmasq[1846]: lese /etc/resolv.conf
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop dnsmasq[1846]: Benutze Namensserver 127.0.0.53#53
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop dnsmasq[1846]: Cache geleert
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop dnsmasq[1846]: lese /etc/resolv.conf
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop dnsmasq[1846]: Benutze Namensserver 127.0.0.53#53
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop dnsmasq[1846]: Cache geleert
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop dnsmasq[1846]: lese /etc/resolv.conf
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop dnsmasq[1846]: Benutze Namensserver 127.0.0.53#53
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop dnsmasq[1846]: Cache geleert
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop deja-dup-monito[3587]: Source ID 112 was not found when attempting to remove it
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop gsd-sharing[2454]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit gnome-user-share-webdav.service not loaded.
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop gsd-sharing[2454]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit rygel.service not loaded.
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop dbus-daemon[1302]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop gsd-sharing[2454]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit gnome-remote-desktop.service not loaded.
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'connectivity-change': new request (1 scripts)
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'connectivity-change': start running ordered scripts...
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:2 'down' [enp37s0]: new request (1 scripts)
Apr 15 17:52:52 julian-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:2 'down' [enp37s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Apr 15 17:52:53 julian-desktop wpa_supplicant[1338]: wlp36s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-95 retry=1
Apr 15 17:52:53 julian-desktop goa-daemon[2337]: goa_http_client_check() failed: 2 — Fehler beim Auflösen von »kmu.files.cnow.at«: Der Name oder der Dienst ist nicht bekannt
Apr 15 17:52:53 julian-desktop goa-daemon[2337]: /org/gnome/OnlineAccounts/Accounts/account_1547674158_0: Setting AttentionNeeded to TRUE because EnsureCredentials() failed with: Ungültiges Passwort für Benutzer »julian.fesel@inode.at« (goa-error-quark, 0): Rechnername konnte nicht aufgelöst werden (goa-error-quark, 4)
Apr 15 17:52:54 julian-desktop wpa_supplicant[1338]: wlp36s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-95 retry=1
Apr 15 17:52:54 julian-desktop goa-daemon[2337]: goa_http_client_check() failed: 2 — Fehler beim Auflösen von »kmu.files.cnow.at«: Der Name oder der Dienst ist nicht bekannt
Apr 15 17:52:55 julian-desktop wpa_supplicant[1338]: wlp36s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-95 retry=1
Apr 15 17:53:06 julian-desktop wpa_supplicant[1338]: message repeated 11 times: [ wlp36s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-95 retry=1]
Apr 15 17:53:06 julian-desktop NetworkManager[1320]: <info>  [1555343586.8275] device (enp37s0): carrier: link connected
Apr 15 17:53:06 julian-desktop NetworkManager[1320]: <info>  [1555343586.8279] device (enp37s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 15 17:53:06 julian-desktop NetworkManager[1320]: <info>  [1555343586.8291] policy: auto-activating connection 'Kabelgebundene Verbindung 1'
Apr 15 17:53:06 julian-desktop kernel: [ 1678.238273] igb 0000:25:00.0 enp37s0: igb: enp37s0 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
Apr 15 17:53:06 julian-desktop NetworkManager[1320]: <info>  [1555343586.8307] device (enp37s0): Activation: starting connection 'Kabelgebundene Verbindung 1' (599cf1b6-92de-3ca4-a47a-a9b8f9c1b24f)
Apr 15 17:53:06 julian-desktop NetworkManager[1320]: <info>  [1555343586.8310] device (enp37s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 15 17:53:06 julian-desktop NetworkManager[1320]: <info>  [1555343586.8313] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Apr 15 17:53:06 julian-desktop NetworkManager[1320]: <info>  [1555343586.8318] device (enp37s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 15 17:53:06 julian-desktop NetworkManager[1320]: <info>  [1555343586.8325] device (enp37s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 15 17:53:06 julian-desktop NetworkManager[1320]: <info>  [1555343586.8329] dhcp4 (enp37s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Apr 15 17:53:06 julian-desktop NetworkManager[1320]: <info>  [1555343586.8347] dhcp4 (enp37s0): dhclient started with pid 4755
Apr 15 17:53:06 julian-desktop dhclient[4755]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.178.42 on enp37s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x6d294be5)
Apr 15 17:53:07 julian-desktop wpa_supplicant[1338]: wlp36s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-95 retry=1
Apr 15 17:53:08 julian-desktop wpa_supplicant[1338]: wlp36s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-95 retry=1
Apr 15 17:53:08 julian-desktop goa-daemon[2337]: goa_http_client_check() failed: 2 — Fehler beim Auflösen von »kmu.files.cnow.at«: Der Name oder der Dienst ist nicht bekannt
Apr 15 17:53:08 julian-desktop avahi-daemon[1334]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp37s0.IPv6 with address fe80::4a89:a9d2:49ca:9df4.
Apr 15 17:53:08 julian-desktop avahi-daemon[1334]: New relevant interface enp37s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Apr 15 17:53:08 julian-desktop avahi-daemon[1334]: Registering new address record for fe80::4a89:a9d2:49ca:9df4 on enp37s0.*.
Apr 15 17:53:09 julian-desktop wpa_supplicant[1338]: wlp36s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-95 retry=1
Apr 15 17:53:09 julian-desktop dhclient[4755]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.178.42 on enp37s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x6d294be5)
Apr 15 17:53:09 julian-desktop dhclient[4755]: DHCPACK of 192.168.178.42 from 192.168.178.1
Apr 15 17:53:09 julian-desktop NetworkManager[1320]: <info>  [1555343589.1435] dhcp4 (enp37s0):   address 192.168.178.42
Apr 15 17:53:09 julian-desktop NetworkManager[1320]: <info>  [1555343589.1435] dhcp4 (enp37s0):   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Apr 15 17:53:09 julian-desktop NetworkManager[1320]: <info>  [1555343589.1435] dhcp4 (enp37s0):   gateway 192.168.178.1
Apr 15 17:53:09 julian-desktop NetworkManager[1320]: <info>  [1555343589.1435] dhcp4 (enp37s0):   lease time 864000
Apr 15 17:53:09 julian-desktop NetworkManager[1320]: <info>  [1555343589.1435] dhcp4 (enp37s0):   nameserver '192.168.178.1'
Apr 15 17:53:09 julian-desktop NetworkManager[1320]: <info>  [1555343589.1435] dhcp4 (enp37s0):   domain name 'fritz.box'
Apr 15 17:53:09 julian-desktop NetworkManager[1320]: <info>  [1555343589.1436] dhcp4 (enp37s0): state changed unknown -> bound
Apr 15 17:53:09 julian-desktop avahi-daemon[1334]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp37s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.178.42.
Apr 15 17:53:09 julian-desktop avahi-daemon[1334]: New relevant interface enp37s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Apr 15 17:53:09 julian-desktop avahi-daemon[1334]: Registering new address record for 192.168.178.42 on enp37s0.IPv4.
Apr 15 17:53:09 julian-desktop NetworkManager[1320]: <info>  [1555343589.1456] device (enp37s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 15 17:53:09 julian-desktop dhclient[4755]: bound to 192.168.178.42 -- renewal in 360679 seconds.
Apr 15 17:53:09 julian-desktop whoopsie[2042]: [17:53:09] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Apr 15 17:53:09 julian-desktop NetworkManager[1320]: <info>  [1555343589.1466] device (enp37s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 15 17:53:09 julian-desktop NetworkManager[1320]: <info>  [1555343589.1469] device (enp37s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 15 17:53:09 julian-desktop NetworkManager[1320]: <info>  [1555343589.1471] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Apr 15 17:53:09 julian-desktop NetworkManager[1320]: <info>  [1555343589.1487] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Apr 15 17:53:09 julian-desktop NetworkManager[1320]: <info>  [1555343589.1488] policy: set 'Kabelgebundene Verbindung 1' (enp37s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Apr 15 17:53:09 julian-desktop NetworkManager[1320]: <info>  [1555343589.1492] device (enp37s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Apr 15 17:53:09 julian-desktop dnsmasq[1846]: lese /etc/resolv.conf
Apr 15 17:53:09 julian-desktop dnsmasq[1846]: Benutze Namensserver 127.0.0.53#53
Apr 15 17:53:09 julian-desktop dnsmasq[1846]: Cache geleert
Apr 15 17:53:09 julian-desktop dnsmasq[1846]: lese /etc/resolv.conf
Apr 15 17:53:09 julian-desktop dnsmasq[1846]: Benutze Namensserver 127.0.0.53#53
Apr 15 17:53:09 julian-desktop dnsmasq[1846]: Cache geleert
Apr 15 17:53:09 julian-desktop dnsmasq[1846]: lese /etc/resolv.conf
Apr 15 17:53:09 julian-desktop dnsmasq[1846]: Benutze Namensserver 127.0.0.53#53
Apr 15 17:53:09 julian-desktop dnsmasq[1846]: Cache geleert
Apr 15 17:53:09 julian-desktop dbus-daemon[1302]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.13' (uid=0 pid=1320 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Apr 15 17:53:09 julian-desktop dnsmasq[1846]: lese /etc/resolv.conf
Apr 15 17:53:09 julian-desktop dnsmasq[1846]: Benutze Namensserver 127.0.0.53#53
Apr 15 17:53:09 julian-desktop dnsmasq[1846]: Cache geleert
Apr 15 17:53:09 julian-desktop dnsmasq[1846]: lese /etc/resolv.conf
Apr 15 17:53:09 julian-desktop dnsmasq[1846]: Benutze Namensserver 127.0.0.53#53
Apr 15 17:53:09 julian-desktop dnsmasq[1846]: Cache geleert
```

I am fairly certain that the problem is ubuntu/pc related and that connection cable and router are fine. I tried using the same cable connection with another computer and there I don't experiance any problems. I also already updated the system but it makes no difference.

I am not really a ubuntu superuser and kind of at a loss on how to solve/start solving this issue (with the exception of drastic measures like reinstalling the system).
Please let me know if I can provide any additional info.

EDIT 1 - ADDITIONAL SYSTEM INFORMATION:

lshw:

```
julian@julian-desktop:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:24:00.0
       logical name: wlp36s0
       version: 10
       serial: 3c:6a:a7:4e:40:f8
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-47-generic firmware=29.1044073957.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:70 memory:f7600000-f7601fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: I211 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:25:00.0
       logical name: enp37s0
       version: 03
       serial: 70:85:c2:a8:bb:7f
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.4.0-k duplex=full firmware=0. 4-1 ip=192.168.178.42 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:40 memory:f7500000-f751ffff ioport:f000(size=32) memory:f7520000-f7523fff
```

dnsmasq:

```
julian@julian-desktop:~$ dpkg -l *dnsmasq*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
un  dnsmasq        <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  dnsmasq-base   2.79-1       amd64        Small caching DNS proxy and DHCP/
un  dnsmasq-base-l <none>       <none>       (no description available)
```

resolv:

```
julian@julian-desktop:~$ ls -al /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Okt 19 23:30 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
julian@julian-desktop:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
search fritz.box
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `dpkg -l *dnsmasq*` and `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks for responding! I added the requested information.

Comment: You probably have a cabling problem. Please describe your cabling from the computer, all the way to the router/modem. Do you have extra cables on hand?

Comment: @heynnema I have a 5 m cable going from the pc to a wall outlet which then connects to the router via a >20 m cable in the wall. With some effort I could try out another outlet. But I already tested the connection with my macbook and I don't experience the problem there. Could it be that my pc network interface is malfunctioning? Do you know of a hardware test that I could perform?
But I will try whether another outlet works, but it will take some time. I will also try a direct connection between my macbook and the pc. Then I can exclude a broken NIC.

Comment: If you look closely at the `lshw` command output, you'll see `speed=100Mbit/s`, and that's the problem I'm looking to fix. It should read 1Gbits/s or 1000Kbits/s. Change the cabling, using cat 5E or cat 6 cables, rerun the `lshw`, and recheck that value. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema You were right! I now moved the whole PC and connected it directly to the router using a cat 6 cable. This results in a 1Gbits/s connection and the network dropping was gone. The problem is now that I would need to connect the PC through the wall cabling, which was established more than ten years ago and is probably of a lower grade. What I don't understand is why I don't have the problems on my macbook using the older cables. I just rechecked: On my macbook I also have a 100Mbit/s connection but no drops.

Comment: Let me put together a quick answer for you, and maybe you can accept it if it was helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments...

We did various diagnostics, but `sudo lshw -C network` shows the problem.

```
 *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: I211 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:25:00.0
       logical name: enp37s0
       version: 03
       serial: 70:85:c2:a8:bb:7f
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.4.0-k duplex=full firmware=0. 4-1 ip=192.168.178.42 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:40 memory:f7500000-f751ffff ioport:f000(size=32) memory:f7520000-f7523fff
```

Where it shows `speed=100Mbit/s`, that should read `1Gbit/s`. This indicates that most likely you've got a cabling problem. Replace ethernet cables using cat 5E or cat 6 cables, until the `lshw` output looks correct.

**Update #1:**

When cabled directly to the router using cat 6 cables, the system is working fine. The wall wiring is not up to the task of 1G LAN speeds.

**Update #2:**

The old ethernet cables installed in the wall can't support 1G network speeds of a new router. The new router has settings to allow the router to limit itself to 10/100 speeds, and installing a 10/100 switch between the PC and the router, and that seems to also work with the old wall wiring.

Comment: Just for clarification: It's only half a solution because the cables are not broken - they are just limiting the speed and I still don't understand why Ubuntu cannot handle this. The mac has no problem with this. But if I replace the cables in the wall then this should solve the problem. Anyway: THANKS!

Comment: @das_Urmel As you found out, both Ubuntu and the Mac suffered from the same poor connections... probably, as you mentioned, due to the 10 year old cables in the wall. But it's not only a speed issue, it's an interference issue. Probably more wiring needs to be replaced if it's that old... if you want your solid network connections :-)

Comment: @das_Urmel The Mac may, or may not, have a Gbit network interface like the Ubuntu machine does. You'd have to look. You might also check the system error log to see if it was logging ethernet errors.

Comment: The mac definetly does not have drops in the connection and it is also weird that the same old cables worked without problems with ubuntu before I changed the router. So I suspect that there is still something in the bushes. But I agree that having new cables is the nicest solution ... they are just installed in the wall, which makes it problematic :-)

Comment: @das_Urmel ah, tell more more about the new router. Why did you change it? What make/model is it? Does it have 1G LAN ports (probably), whereas the old router didn't (probably). You have to share all these details when asking for help :-) How long is the run from the wall jack to the router?

Comment: The old one was an ADB av4202n ab-000-1a1-bx with four 10/100 Mbits/s ethernet ports. The new one is a Fritz!box 7530 with four 10/100/1000 Mbits/s ethernet ports. Basically everything else has been left unchanged. Port-Router cable distance is 1.5 m. Given your comments on the speed I just checked the settings of the new router and saw that one can limit the ports to 100 Mbits/s. Doing so seems to have removed the problems so far. I will get back to you tomorrow if it's lasting! Then you could update the solution.

Comment: @das_Urmel exactly. The new router supports 1G LAN connections, but your wiring is not up to that task. I'd still get the cabling up to modern code... as 1G LAN speeds is 10 times what you're able to get now with the old wiring and the slower setting. I'll update my answer.

Comment: The cost of replacing the cables is at the moment simply too high for the speed up (which is right now anyway limited by the internet connection). Here is what worked now: Reducing the router speed actually didn't work BUT: I put a 10/100 Mbits/s switch between router and PC and now it works :-) Slightly dirty but good enough for now. Many thanks again for your help and for pointing me in the right direction!!!

Comment: Creative solution. Remember, that if you're transferring large files between computers, that 1G network speed would also make a big difference. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you're working with a problematic cable, you can disable auto-negotiation so it doesn't keep trying to renegotiate then fail.

```
sudo ethtool --change eno0 speed 100 autoneg off
```

Use `ifconfig` to find the name of the correct interface you would like to fix. Mine was `eno0` When you get a new cable, turn autoneg back on.